# Convert float32 to float64 in ndarray.take() with 'out' argument

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `float32` NumPy array (obtained from a C library) and I want to copy some of the values, specified by 'fancy' indexing, into an existing `float64` array.

So far I have:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0], dtype=np.float32)
b = np.empty(2, dtype=np.float64)
b[:] = a[[2, 0]]
```

That does what I want, but I wanted to avoid the [additional copy caused by the 'fancy' indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays). So I tried to use `ndarray.take()` with an `out` argument:

```
a.take([2, 0], out=b)
```

This doesn't work, instead it raises a `TypeError`:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('float32') according to the rule 'safe'

How can I get this to work?
I want to avoid copies and, more importantly, memory allocations during the assignment step.

I found a `casting` argument in  [`numpy.nditer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) and it seems that `casting='same_kind'` would fit for my situation. Is there a way to force this setting when using `ndarray.take()`?

Comment: It is a bug in numpy. There is a pull request open to fix it, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4246), but it still needs some work before it can be merged. Feel free to chime in the github issue discussion, hopefully it will make it into numpy 1.10...